# If $A,B$ are positive operators, then $\sqrt A B \sqrt A \geq0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory

If $A,B$ are positive operators, then $\sqrt A B \sqrt A \geq0$?

One may assume that the operators act on $\mathbb R^n$, i.e., on a finite-dimensional space.

Of course, the result is true if $A$ and $B$ commute, but what about the general case?

Comment: Is $A$ self-adjoint?

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes, if the operators act on $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: Then note that whenever $B$ is positive and $P$ is nonsingular, the operator $P^\top BP$ is positive,

Comment: $\forall x\in\Bbb R^n,$ $$ x^t\sqrt A B \sqrt A x=(\sqrt B \sqrt A x)^t (\sqrt B \sqrt A x)\geq0.$$

Comment: Are you asking about their positive semi-definiteness (since we're in the finite-dimensional setting)?

Comment: @AnneBauval That answers my question, thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proof for Semidefinite symmetric matrix product](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1550774/proof-for-semidefinite-symmetric-matrix-product) or this? [Is $A^TBA$ positive semidefinite, for any square matrix $B$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1610149)